# Does a php imagick script using resizeImage with imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS manage to utilise multiple cores?

Tags: php, imagick

I believe that PHP is single-threaded, but read that the imagemagick code is multi-threaded.  I'm not sure what the outcome is?

Thank you

Comment: PHP deals with an HTTP request in a single thread. Behind the scenes, it _can_ be multithreaded, but it's not needed at all. Any extension can implement whatever it wants, from being multithreaded to async etc. Read the code of the mentioned function in imagemagick's source and check whether it threads for any reason or not. PHP won't stop it if it does.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If you have big enough images to be worried about this, I'd recommend calling ImageMagick from the command line through exec or similar. Having a webserver process spending a lot of time in a library call isn't great.

Comment: I'm led to believe that exec performs worse than imagick from what I've read on the subject, due to constantly having to spawn the entire imagemagick code. I have a twelve core Xeon but will be getting 50,000+ full res camera images uploaded per day in a couple of weeks. I have a queue set up but would like to make any changes I can to minimise people having to wait for their photos to be processed

Comment: Start a CLI process that processes each image sequentially, no need to start it for every image. You said you have a queue set up. Website > Upload image > put the image's path in queue > have a cli process (or processes) take the path from the queue, do the processing, move on to next image. Your website, after upload, can just notify the user with message "thank you, your image is being processed, check back in a few minutes". From there on you've got other options for notifying people that something's done, but I've gone offtopic as it is..